# Implementation of Directed Weighted Graph

Tags: java, implementation, adjacency-matrix, directed-graph, weighted-graph

Want to know if there was anything here that seems incorrect. The only suggestion I have gotten that I havent added was to fill the matrix to integer.max_value. Also the weight has to be the parameter for all edges and weight goes to 0 when we remove edge just in case there is confusion. If you see anything incorrect please let me know (java).

```
public class Graph {
private int size;
private int adjacentMatrix[][];


public Graph (int size) {
this.size = size;
adjacentMatrix = new int [size][size];
}


public void addEdge (int source, int destination, int weight) {
if (source < size && source >= 0 && destination < size && destination >= 0)
    adjacentMatrix [source][destination] = weight;
}


public void removeEdge (int source, int destination, int weight) {
if (source < size && source >= 0 && destination < size && destination >= 0)
    adjacentMatrix [source][destination] = 0; 
}


//function to check if edges are connected
public boolean isEdge(int source, int destination) {
if (source >= 0 && source < size && destination >= 0 && destination < size) {
    return adjacentMatrix[source][destination] > 0;
 }
else
    return false;
  }   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The `isEdge` method does not take into account that edges may have negative weights
- OR, if negative weights are not allowed, `addEdge` should check if the weight is negative
- `addEdge` and `removeEdge` should have some way to tell you if the edge was really added or removed. For example, return boolean `true` if the graph was modifed, OR throw an exception if not accepted.
- You can't have fractional weights - maybe that's ok for your use case.